# Display all rows in Symfony 3

Tags: symfony, query-builder, dql

I have a form which has `EntityType:class` below in Symfony 3 or SF3, as you can see I am calling the function from method `findAllActiveBuyingCurrencies` from `BranchCurrencyRepository`.

```
->add('currency', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => BranchCurrency::class,
                'choice_value' => 'rate',
                'choice_label' => function($currency){
                    return $currency->getName() . ' (' . $currency->getCode() .') - '.$currency->getRate().'';
                },
                'placeholder' => 'Choose currency',
                'query_builder' => function (BranchCurrencyRepository $er) {
                    return $er->findAllActiveBuyingCurrencies();
                },
            ])
```

The functions does it's thing and displays all currencies inside the form (Option)

But, I wanted to display all currencies and my problem is, only 25 currencies are displayed.

Please see my code displaying all currencies

// branchCurrenciesRepository

```
 public function findAllActiveBuyingCurrencies() {

        return $this->createQueryBuilder('currency')
            ->where('currency.type = :type')
            ->setParameter('type', BranchCurrencyConstant::Buying);



    }
```

View

```
<div class="col-3">
        <label for="" class="required">
            <strong> Currency <span class="highlight-red"></span></strong>
        </label>
        {{ form_widget(form.currency) }}
        {% if not form.currency.vars.valid %}
            <p class="mt10" style="color: #DC2B1B;">{{ form.currency.vars.errors[0].message }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
```

Comment: Show us your view please

Comment: Your function findAllActiveBuyingCurrencies will return all currencies which her type is Buying. Other currencies which the type doesn't match to Bying aren't be displayed

Comment: @Mcsky please see updated question above with view code.

Comment: @MohamedBenHENDA yes exactly. but the thing is, not returning all data, only 25.

Comment: When you remove the condition "if not form.currency.vars.valid" in the view, ca you see al currencies in the form?

Comment: I test, and still not working @MohamedBenHENDA

Comment: Can you check the SQL query executed to populate your `currency entity` field. Do you see a LIMIT order ?

Comment: Can you give us from your table a row of a diplayed currency and another row of a not diplayed currency, so we can check the diff?

Comment: @Mcsky I haven't see any limits when I generated SQL in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Could you provide us the real SQL query executed by php to populate your form entry. You'll see it under the doctrine part of the `profiler` debug via `http://yourlocaldev/_profiler` by default

Comment: @Mcsky `SELECT b0_.id AS id_0, b0_.rate AS rate_1, b0_.type AS type_2, b0_.code AS code_3, b0_.name AS name_4, b0_.created_at AS created_at_5, b0_.updated_at AS updated_at_6, b0_.branch_id AS branch_id_7, b0_.currency_id AS currency_id_8 FROM branch_currency b0_ WHERE b0_.type = ? LIMIT 999`

Comment: Also, I notice that there is an error in entity 
`MontealBundle\Entity\User 
The association MontealBundle\Entity\User#company refers to the inverse side field MontealBundle\Entity\Company#User which does not exist.
The association MontealBundle\Entity\User#branch refers to the inverse side field MontealBundle\Entity\Branch#User which does not exist.`